# FAIL : NameError: name 'urlparse' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework, python-3.7

I am trying to make a simple script using robotframework-sudslibrary to add a string but it got the following fail on IDE tool (RED):

```
Starting test: Test.Test.Add Two String  
20191012 01:12:04.165 : FAIL : NameError: name **'urlparse'** is not defined  
Ending test: Test.Test.Add Two String
```

Note that: The library(urllib.parse) already added in robot referenced libraries

```
*** Settings ***

Library    SudsLibrary

Library    urllib.parse

*** Variables ***

${INPUT_DATA_DIR}    ${EXECDIR}/Tests

*** Test Cases ***

Add In Calculator

    Create Soap Client     ${INPUT_DATA_DIR}/WSDL.wsdl
    ${req}  Call Soap Method  Add  1    4
    Should Be Equal As Numbers     ${req}   5
    ${recive}  Get Last Received
    Log To Console    ${recive}
```

Can you please help me how to fix this?

This wsdl file, I get here: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

Comment: I used *robotframework-sudslibrary3* Last released: Jun 26, 2019

Answer (score 2):

It works fine when importing the following parses into Sudslibary on my PC.

*from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urljoin, urlparse*